# manejar zonas horarias en Azure webservices

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure-storage, timezone

tengo un sistema de marcas de entrada o salida para trabajo remoto. el sistema esta casi completo (autenticacion, manejo de sesiones, administracion de los datos de usuarios, generacion de marcas y notificacion por correo), pero tengo un problema: lo almacené en Azure Web Apps en EEUU, y la marca de entrada o salida se genera con la hora internacional, y no con la de Costa Rica (GMT -6).

[image: Imagen de muestra]

este es el codigo en C# donde se crea la marca. vease que incluso intente que la variable DateTime.Now se convirtiera a mi zona horaria, pero sigo sin lograrlo

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Web.Security;

namespace User_Login_CS
{
    public partial class Home : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!this.Page.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                FormsAuthentication.RedirectToLoginPage();
            }
            
        }
        protected void CrearMarca(object sender, EventArgs e, string tipomarca)
        {
            DateTime now = DateTime.Now.ToLocalTime();
            string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["constr"].ConnectionString;
            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr))
            {
                string comando = "INSERT INTO [marcas].[dbo].[Regs]([Username],[CreatedDate],[MarkType])VALUES('" + this.Page.User.Identity.Name + "','"+now+"','"+ tipomarca + "');";
                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(comando))
                {
                    cmd.Connection = con;
                    con.Open();
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    con.Close();
                    
                }
            }

        }

        protected void cmd_entrada_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            CrearMarca(sender, e, "Entrada");
            string message = string.Empty;
            message = "Marca de entrada realizada";
            ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(), "alert", "alert('" + message + "');", true);
            
        }

        protected void cmd_salida_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            CrearMarca(sender, e, "Salida");
            string message = string.Empty;
            message = "Marca de salida realizada";
            ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(), "alert", "alert('" + message + "');", true);
           
        }
    }
}
```

hay forma de corregirlo, o de "engañar" al sistema restando 6 horas a la marca por medio de codigo, para que me muestre las horas reales??

gracias

Comment: Pues, haces conversiones de zona horaria en la presentación y listo. Por otro lado, cada que se trabaja con zonas horarias, se recomienda utilizar UTC+00, y a partir de ahí convertir lo que se tenga que convertir. Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Debes establecer la variable WEBSITE_TIME_ZONE en Application settings > en App settings, ahí añade esta configuración

- Key = WEBSITE_TIME_ZONE
- Value = La zona horaria que deseas

Más info aquí https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/troubleshoot/azure/app-service/web-apps-configuration-and-management-faqs#how-do-i-set-the-server-time-zone-for-my-web-app

Comment: Hice la configuracion que me indicas y funcina en la configuracion del app, pero sigue desplegando la hora incorrectamente para mi pais. incluso intente corregir la hora desde SQL haciendo que la hora ingresada sea la de mi zona horaria: INSERT INTO [marcas].[dbo].[Regs]([Username],[CreatedDate],[MarkType])VALUES('jhernandez',(SELECT GETDATE() AT TIME ZONE ('Central America Standard Time')),'Entrada')